# Fact retrieval using Mistral-7B-v0.1 (base mode)

Tags: algorithm, information-retrieval, large-language-model, pre-trained-model, beam-search

**Context**

I pre-trained the mistral  `Mistral-7B-v0.1`  (base model) using the `pretrain_chinese_llama_lora.ipynb` script provided in the [Chinese-LLaMA-Alpaca](https://github.com/ymcui/Chinese-LLaMA-Alpaca) repository on the Github.

I trained the base model for text completion task using on 50 lines of text containing facts - places, persons, historical & geographical facts.

The lines representing the facts about a single entity (like place, a person,....) are not continuous. For example:

```
<fact #1 about New York>

<fact #1 about John Doe>

<fact #2 about John Doe>

<fact #1 about a river and geography>

<fact #2 about New York>

... 
... 
...

<fact #3 about New York>
```

Now my goal is to retrieve all the facts about `New York` using text completion prompt after pre-training the model for text completion task.

**My Observation**

I see that even after using the [Diverse beam search decoding](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/generation_strategies#diverse-beam-search-decoding), the model is not able to retrieve all the facts/context related to New York.

**What did I try?**

The snippet for the inference is as follows:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = pt_model.generate(**model_input, max_new_tokens=100, repetition_penalty=1.15,
                                    num_beams=15, num_beam_groups=15, diversity_penalty=2.0,
                                    num_return_sequences=15)
    model_output = tokenizer.batch_decode(outputs, skip_special_tokens=True)
```

**Why did I didn't use database / RAG**:

1. I have a 1000s of PDFs of data which I can't obviously go through and create DB scripts to store the facts for the entities I am interested into.
2. RAG will possibly induce similar (not exact) facts based on similarity search which I want to avoid.
3. I want to further fine tune this model for Q&A on my specific use-case. Hence I need to retrieve as much as facts as possible.

Comment: With pre-train you really mean you trained the model from scratch? So it hasn't seen anything else than your 50 lines of text?

Comment: No sir, not from scratch. Just trained the base model.

Comment: Further training or fine-tuning LLMs can lead to "catastrophic forgetting". Have you tried few shots learning? Just pass the 50 examples with your question in the same context like so: https://www.promptingguide.ai/techniques/fewshot

Comment: @r000bin I think you are right. I pretrained (Stage 2 pretraining - which uses CLM using PEFT. Link - https://github.com/ymcui/Chinese-LLaMA-Alpaca/wiki/Pretraining-Script) on a pdf and saved the model as checkpoint. I further pre-trained this checkpoint on another pdf. Now the model is not able to answer questions related to the first pdf.